# How to generate the equal number of groups per week that have members that change the group every week

Tags: excel

I have been trying to create an excel that I can use to assign members to a group per week. I need to make sure that each member is in the different group every week.

Below is my excel and here is the formula I use in B3

```
=INDEX(UNIQUE(RANDARRAY(2, 10, 1, 11)), SEQUENCE(1), {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11})
```

The issue i cannot fix is the fact that the groups differ in sizes? Any ideas please.

```
Week    1   2
PPLs        
1       7   8
2       6   11
3       1   3
4   2   7
5   9   7
6   2   10
7   4   8
8   4   5
9   10  8
10  8   9
11  3   6
12  8   6
13  7   9
14  7   8
15  5   8
16  5   8
17  8   8
18  8   10
19  4   9
20  3   2
21  10  9
22  2   10
23  10  6
24  9   3
25  4   9
26  7   6
27  10  7
28  7   7
29  10  5
30  2   5
31  6   6
32  8   8
33  4   4
34  9   10
35  5   9
36  9   7
37  5   7
38  10  9
39  2   10
40  6   5
41  9   2
```

Comment: How many members per group ? How many member in total ?

Comment: it would be 10 groups. so one group would have 5 members.

Answer (score 0):

2 thoughts : simple&(somewhat)repeatable OR noExcel&random.

[ simple&(somewhat)repeatable ]

2 sets only.

Set 1 : group 1 is {member 1-10}, group 2 is {member 11-20} ..  group 10 is {member 91-100}

Set 2 : group 1 is {member 1,11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91}, group 2 is {member 2,12,22,32,42,52,62,72,82,92} ..  group 10 is {member 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100}

p/s : although member 1 is always is group 1.. I'd consider it is as a valid group change, since ALL other members of group 1 had changed.

[ noExcel&random ]

Ever heard of 10x10 sudoku? it is widely available online. I have no specific one.. But Sudoku, IS what I meant by noExcel.

example 10x10 sudoku solution :

[image: solved 10x10 sudoku]

how to use it :

1. get 5 different (different is important) solved 10x10 sudoku set, and put it one on top of each other. We should get a 10(col)x50(row) table.
2. Sort by all 1st row, shall have the sequence (from top, in column 1) : 1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3, .. 9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,10
3. Since we have 50 members (10groups, 5members each). Column 1 will be the assigned group for 50 respective (row) member in week1, Column 2 will be the assigned group for week2... and so on.

if every week is different group, then by week 11 it will come back to his/her original group. OR .. another (5 10x10 sudoku) set perhaps?

(If the idea is unclear.. please ask)
AFAIK. with the rules of sudoku itself, each member(row) will have a different group each week(column), and each element (group number) WILL be repeated for 5 times for each week(column). Thus, solve the

> the fact that the groups differ in sizes

part. (please share if this doesn't work though..)

ref : I used https://sudokuspoiler.azurewebsites.net/Sudoku/Sudoku10 to solve http://www.sudoku4me.com/sudoku%2010x10.php puzzle (this solver need 0 to be replaced with 10). As long as it is a valid sudoku solution, it should be fine. Some sudoku use letters instead of numbers. Still, the idea applies.

p/s :  I tried excel built in random number generator to generate a ranked (sorted) list, but still end up unable get consistent 5 members per group arrangement, with different group each week (same trouble as OP). I had a fond memory with 9x9 Sudoku, glad to know it came in handy for this solution.